# Error while creating a jar file with BlueJ

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar, bluej

I was trying to create a jar file with Bluej and for some reason BlueJ would not let me include libraries that I was using (Specifically the Amazon SDK for Java)

It gave off an error "jar file could not be written correctly, check for access rights" or something along the lines of that. Is this just a BlueJ problem or is there something I need to do before creating a jar file that needs to include third party libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question can be found here, at the [BlueJ FAQ](https://www.bluej.org/faq.html) website:

https://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__

The website describes three ways of doing this in BlueJ. The first way is via the "Preferences" dialog. Open the "Preferences" dialogue and select the "Libraries" tab. Then add the location where your classes are as a library path. Restart BlueJ - done. The selected libraries will now be available in all projects that you open.